# How to extract text after word using reg

Tags: python-3.x, regex

I want to use regex to extract text after the word code=

```
import re
redirect_url = "https://appf.io/oauth_callback?code=rRRtydLv-70OBNniMSHbOiZv-AqryJrX50hht_6HBak"
print(re.search(r'/(oauth_callback\?code=.+)$/', str(redirect_url)))
```

Solution: rRRtydLv-70OBNniMSHbOiZv-AqryJrX50hht_6HBak

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you want to extract text after a certain string.
You can make use of string manipulation. To do this following your example would look like

```
redirect_url = "https://appf.io/oauth_callback?code=rRRtydLv-70OBNniMSHbOiZv-AqryJrX50hht_6HBak"
print(redirect_url.split("oauth_callback?code=")[1])
```

I removed the backslash since we dont need to escape the special character

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `re` you can try ([regex101](https://regex101.com/r/GD24DE/1)):

```py
import re

redirect_url = "https://appf.io/oauth_callback?code=rRRtydLv-70OBNniMSHbOiZv-AqryJrX50hht_6HBak"

code = re.search(r'^(?=.*/oauth_callback).*\bcode=([^?&]+)', redirect_url)
if code:
    print(code.group(1))
```

Prints:

```
rRRtydLv-70OBNniMSHbOiZv-AqryJrX50hht_6HBak
```

---

At the beginning of the regular expression we check if there's `/oauth_callback` part:

```
^(?=.*/oauth_callback)
```

If yes then we select all characters after the `code=`:

```
.*\bcode=([^?&]+)
```